# Rewriting H(jw) in exponential form

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

[Link to equation in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNuJP.png)

Why can H(jw) be expressed as the absolute value of H(jw) multiplied by an exponent? And what is the meaning behind the actual power (j*theta(jw))?

Answer (score 0):

For any complex number $z$ one can rewrite it in polar form $z = |z|e^{i \arg(z)}$ which is presumably what they did here.